# Register super/win key press in qemu

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, qemu

I'm setting up a VM of my Linux setup using qemu by directly running the .img file through qemu-system-x86_64.

I've got it working, however when I try to do a keybinding with the `Super` key in my VM, it doesn't register in the VM, rather in my host system. (In my case, pressing `Super`+`Return` creates a new terminal window in my host desktop, rather than a new terminal inside of the VM).

How can I either redirect the `Super` key to register inside of the VM when it is focused, or somehow register the `Super` key through some other means in qemu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Toggle "Menu -> View -> [x] Grab on Hover".  That'll send all keyboard input (including hotkeys) to the guest when the qemu window has the mouse focus.

Answer (score 1):

If you want qemu to grab focus automatically when the mouse hovers inside the qemu window, check "View -> Grab on Hover". Press Ctrl+Alt+G to return focus to the host machine.

If you do not want qemu to "steal" focus on mouse hover, having the "Grab on Hover" option unchecked and just using "View -> Grab Input" (Ctrl+Alt+G), when the mouse is over the qemu window will explicitly trigger focusing the qemu window.

Comment: We expect posts here to be self-sufficient and free-standing.  But, if [Gerd Hoffmann’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1652822/150988#1652849) were to disappear, yours would be nearly incomprehensible. Please [edit] it to express  a clear, independent thought.  Ideally, add an explicit reference to the other answer.

Comment: @Scott I've made my post self sufficient. Thanks!